# Convert 11 byte hex string to byte array of size 16

Tags: java, android, hex, arrays

I have a hex string of 11 bytes `"0017333032CD4900186F41"`. I have to convert this string to a byte array and I am doing it fine and getting the correct result. However, following a particular message format, I would like to convert this hex string to a byte array of size 16 instead of 11. Is this possible?

I tried `hex.getBytes("UTF-8")` and this gave me an array of size 32. Is it possible to have a 11 byte hex string as a byte array of 16?

This requirement is in Java for a BlackBerry app. This has been successfully implemented in Android and iPhone. Android is making use of the `ByteConverter` lib in Basic4Android to get the desired result:

```
Dim data() As Byte
data = Bconv.HexToBytes(data_hex)
```

Comment: @Grishu, 'hex string of 11 bytes "0017333032CD4900186F41"' is not code. When editing question, please don't highlight normal text as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hexadecimal string represents a byte with 2 digits (16² = 256).

so pad the string `data_hex` to the right with zeroes till it has a length of 2*16 = 32.
Then do the HexToBytes conversion.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
String s = "0017333032CD4900186F41";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 16);
byte[] a1 = bi.toByteArray();
byte[] a2 = new byte[16];
System.arraycopy(a1, 0, a2, 16 - a1.length, a1.length);
```

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't try this in my BlackBerry app code because BigInteger is not part of any library here.